# How do I condense this jQuery code to avoid repeating?

Tags: html, jquery

I am using jQuery to create a play/pause button for audio. I have made it work for one particular element, but I do need a couple more, and I don't want to use copy and paste. Here is what I have now:

**content.js**

```
var audio1 = document.getElementById('01');
var playButton = document.getElementById('play_1');
var isPlaying = false;

audio1.onplaying = function() {
  isPlaying = true;
};
audio1.onpause = function() {
  isPlaying = false;
};

function play() {
    playButton.addEventListener("click", function(){
        if (isPlaying) {
            audio1.pause();
        } else {
            audio1.play();
        }
    })
};

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", play());

$(document).ready(function() {
  let btn = $("#play_1");
  btn.click(function() {
    btn.toggleClass("paused");
    return false;
  });
});
```

**index.html**

```
<audio id="01" src="..." type="audio/mp3"></audio>
<div class="play" id="play_1"></div>
```

**style.css**

```
.play {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-table;
  width: 0px;
  height: 15px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-bottom: -3px;
  transition: 100ms;
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent rgba(233, 170, 211, 0.5);
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 8px 0 8px 12px;
}

.paused {
  border-style: double;
  border-width: 0px 0 0px 12px;
}

.play:hover {
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent rgba(233, 170, 211, 0.7);
}
.play:active {
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent rgba(233, 170, 211, 0.9);
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterate over all audio elements that match a particular selector and apply the logic needed to each. To get to the corresponding `<div>`, go to its `nextElementSibling`.

```
const manageAudio = (audio) => {
  const playButton = audio.nextElementSibling;
  let isPlaying = false;
  audio.onplaying = function () {
    isPlaying = true;
  };
  audio.onpause = function () {
    isPlaying = false;
  };
  playButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
    if (isPlaying) {
      audio1.pause();
    } else {
      audio1.play();
    }
  })
  $(playButton).click(function () {
    $(playButton).toggleClass("paused");
  });
};

$(document).ready(function () {
  for (const audio of $('.audio')) {
    manageAudio(audio);
  }
});
```

Use the `.audio` class for the audio elements you want to iterate over.